Custom marker in Leafmap
I want to add custom image marker as my point shp in Leafmap. How can we do this in this code or any other alternative? I'm using PNG and path is 'data\point.png'
import leafmap
m = leafmap.Map(center=[23, 69], zoom=4) 
shp_path = 'data/point.shp'  
point_style = {
'color': 'red',             
'radius': 2,              
'opacity': 1.0           
}
m.add_shp(
shp_path,
layer_name='Point Layer',
style=point_style,         
info_mode='on_click'       
)
m

